# How to instruct Ubuntu to take into account spaces when sorting but maintaining case insensitive order?

Tags: file-sorting

Ubuntu does not consider spaces (and other non-alphabetic characters) when sorting, including files.
I am interested in taking them into account in the sorting, but keeping the listing case insensitive.
I know that using LOCALE=C will take these characters into account, but the case insensitive list is lost.
If I have this list of names (they are Spanish):

- Martin Aguado
- Martin Lopez
- Martin Zaplana
- Martinez Sánchez

And I sort them I get this:

- Martin Aguado
- Martinez Sánchez
- Martin Lopez
- Martin Zaplana

What is a Martinez doing mixed with the Martin's?

Is there a way to configure it?

Comment: 'Sort them' ? How do you sort them ?

Comment: Please show us the exact `sort` command you used, the output of the `locale` command on your system, and include your desired output order in the question. AFAIK there is no single `LOCALE` *variable* - you can however use `LC_COLLATE=C` if you want `sort` to use the `C` locale

Comment: ... after playing around with this a little bit, I think the issue may not be spaces, but actually the way that (older) versions of `glibc` handle the unicode `á` character. What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Indeed, unclear in the first place where the sort is happening, with which tool.

Comment: @SorenA I found this problem in gedit,  in the list of files in nemo, listing files in terminal with ls, etc.

Comment: @steeldriver I don't use a command for sorting, my problem is with the default order or when I ask to sort inside an editor.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS x86_64

Comment: @vanadium My issue is not with a place, is with the whole system.